# if $W$ is a subspace of an inner product space $V$, which of the following statements is true?

Tags: linear-algebra

if  $W$ is a subspace of an inner product space $V$, which of the following statements are true?

> > $1)$ there  is  a unique subspace $W'$ such that $W' + W = V$
> >
> > $2)$ there  is  a unique subspace $W'$ such that $W'\oplus  W = V$
> >
> > $3)$ there  is  a unique subspace $ W'$ such that $W' + W = V$ and $\langle w, w '\rangle  = 0 $ for all $w \in  W $  and $w' \in  W' $
> >
> > $4) $ there  is  a unique subspace $W$' such that $W' \oplus  W = V $ and $ \langle w,w '\rangle $ = $0$ for all $ w \in W$ and $w' \in  W' $

I thinks all options $1,2,3,4 $ will be true  because $W' \cap W = \{0\}$

Any Hints/solution

Thanks u

Comment: Why do you say that $W'\cap W=\{0\}$? That's not mentioned in the statement of the problem.

Comment: Note that, in case $1$, we don't require $W' \cap W = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$. This claim is implicit in writing $W' \oplus W = V$, but not in $W' + W = V$. You can take $W$ to be the whole space if you wanted (hint, hint).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos actually i have read that  some  theorem in books  i mean  direct sum properties

Comment: @santosh That's not even a sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) and (2) are certainly false; in fact they're false if $V=\Bbb R^2$ and $W=\{x,0)::x\in\Bbb R\}$.

(3) and (4) are true if $V$ has finite dimension (or if $V$ is a Hilbert space and $W$ is a closed subspace), but they're also false in a general inner-product space.

For example, let $V$ be the space of sequences $x=(x_1,\dots)$ such that all but finitely many of the $x_j$ vanish, with inner product $$(x,y)=\sum x_jy_j.$$Let $W=\{x\in V:\sum x_j=0\}$.

(Users who said (3) and (4) were true presumably had $W'=W^\perp$ in mind. But here it's easy to see that $W^\perp=\{0\}$.)

Similarly if $V$ is a Hilbert space and $W$ is any non-closed subspace: $$W\oplus W^\perp\ne\overline W\oplus W^\perp
=\overline W\oplus\overline W^\perp=V.$$

Comment: thanks  a lots @ David

Comment: Well, it's not *uniqueness* that fails here but *existence*.

Answer (score 1):

1) and 2) are not true: you can take any *nonorthogonal* complement of $W$ as well.

3) the condition implies $W\cap W'=\{0 \}$ so it's the same as 4) which is true in finite dimensions.

Comment: No, (4) is not true, given just that $V is an inner-product space. See my answer for example.

Comment: Hmm.. You must have an infinite dimensional counterexample.

Comment: thanks @ Berci..